# OpenCV face module error

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, face-recognition

I am working for face recognizer in python with opencv 3.3.

But i am getting this error

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
```

I built opencv with opencv_contrib repo an i see face module in directory.

[OpenCV modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mshs3.png)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have the source code there. A simple search will [show you] that the only place this occurs is one comment. This function existed in 2.4.x, it's no longer present. Do a `dir(cv2.face)`. From the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/3.3.0/modules/face/include/opencv2/face.hpp#L157) it seems the whole class is exported, so perhaps you can just directly call the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

From OpenCV 3, you have to install opencv_contrib. Then you can use the submodule "face".
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
Once installed, use cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer() or other face recognizers.